# If the velocity of an object is decreasing at a constant rate, does it mean that it's a uniformly accelerated motion?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration

If the velocity is constantly decreasing from $u$ to $v$ so is it uniformly accelerated motion?

Comment: increase in velocity is called acceleration. Decrease is called deceleration .

Comment: Any change in velocity can be termed "acceleration". Depends on the text.

Comment: The rate of change of velocity is $dv/dt=a$ i.e. the acceleration. If velocity is decreasing at a constant rate, that means $a$ is constant, whether positive or negative. This,unless the velocity is also changing direction, which I think is not an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration is defined as
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = \vec{a}
\end{equation}
I you mean with "decreasing" that $v = |\vec{v}|$ decreases at a constant rate, then $a = |\vec{a}| = a_0$ and the integration of the first equation leads to
\begin{equation}
v(t) = -a_0t + v_0
\end{equation}
with $a_0 > 0$ and $v_0$ some initial velocity.
From this it is easy to see that for fixed time intervals $\Delta t = t_2 - t_1$ the change of velocity $\Delta v$ is always the same regardless of $t_1, t_2$ as long as $\Delta t$ remains fixed. The motion is indeed uniform acceleration.
However, the acceleration takes into account how the velocity-vector changes. Hence changing direction is also due to an acceleration. Take the uniform circular motion, the length of the vector $\vec{v}$ stays everywhere the same but there is an acceleration due to the constant changing of the direction of this vector. This is also uniform acceleration as the the direction of $\vec{a}$ changes, but its length remains fixed.